# MySql_Failover Not working

Tags: mysql

I am able to configure mysql master and slave with Replication,

Now ,I am facing issues in Automatic Failover,

I was followed this link.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication

Can you help me in Failover.

Thanks

Vikash singh

Comment: Any details about your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Database replication doesn't mean it includes automatic failover.**

Example of replication:

INSERT data **to server A** -> Server A accepts the data and puts it into the binary log -> **Server B** fetches the binary log and also accepts the data

**You need a (failover)cluster for that. Galera by MariaDB for example.**

Example of cluster:

INSERT data to **server pool** -> client library selecting **either server A or server B** -> **syncronization** of the data between servers